# Prove that all monads are functors

Tags: category-theory, monads

It is often written that all monads are functors, but it is quite hard to find an actual mathematical proof of it.

A functor is defined as a higher level type defining the `fmap` function:

```
class Functor f where 
   fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It must also preserve composition:

```
fmap (f . g)  ==  fmap f . fmap g
```

And follow the identity law:

```
fmap id == id
```

A monad is defined as:

```
class Monad m where
  (>>=)  :: m a -> (  a -> m b) -> m b
  return ::   a                 -> m a
```

And the `bind` function must follow the three laws: left identity, right identity and associativity.

`fmap` for a monad can be defined as:

```
fmap f xs  =  xs >>= return . f
```

In order to prove that all monads are functors, we must prove that such a `fmap` function follow the composition and identity laws of functors. It's easy enough to prove identity using the left identity law of monads, but I am struggling to show that such definition of `fmap` conserves composition.

Does someone know the proof for this?

Comment: Mathematically, monads are defined to be functors (plus some extra data), so you will not find a proof.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "A monad can be created by defining a type constructor M and two operations: `return` and `bind`."
Note that there is no mention of `fmap` in that definition. If monads don't have `fmap` in their definition, they can't be functors by definition.

Comment: From Wikipedia too: "A monad is a certain type of endofunctor." You refer to a concept in programming which is essentially the same but, frankly, is non-mathematical without a lot more elaboration. For instance, when are two functions equal? If you cannot answer that question then it does not even make sense to talk about composition being preserved.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate to the usual definition of a monad (as a functor plus some structure) that's similar to your Haskell definition has three pieces of structure and three equations.

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category. A monad on $\mathcal C$ consists of a map on objects $T : Ob(\mathcal C) \to Ob(\mathcal C)$, for each object $x \in Ob(\mathcal C)$ a morphism $\eta_x : x \to T(x)$ and for each morphism $f : x \to T(y)$, a morphism $f^T : T(x) \to T(y)$.

This structure should satisfy the equations $(\eta_x)^T = id_{T(x)}$, $f^T \circ \eta_x = f$ and $(f^T \circ g)^T = f^T \circ g^T$.

$T$ corresponds to your type function `m`. $\eta_x$ is the same as `return` and $f^T$ corresponds to the function that takes `x` to `x >>= f`.

---

$T$ can then be extended to morphisms via $T(f) = (\eta_y \circ f)^T$ (where $f : x \to y$).

Then $T(id_x) = (\eta_x \circ id_x)^T = (\eta_x)^T = id_{T(x)}$. Moreover, for $f : y \to z$ and $g : x \to y$,

$$
\begin{align}
T(f) \circ T(g) &= (\eta_z \circ f)^T \circ (\eta_y \circ g)^T\\
&= ((\eta_z \circ f)^T \circ \eta_y \circ g)^T\\
&= (\eta_z \circ f \circ g)^T\\
&= T(f \circ g).
\end{align}
$$

So $T$ is a functor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that this is a math question... Mathematically (as Zhen Lin points out), it's *part of the definition* of a monad that it also be a functor.

The question is really about the haskell typeclasses "Monad" and "Functor", and while these are obviously made to imitate their categorical namesakes, there's no way to guarantee that the monad/functor laws actually hold for your implementation. Moreover, it used to be the case that haskell Monads *weren't required to be Functors*, and some old tutorials still emphasize this fact. This was widely regarded to be a Bad Idea™, especially since any Monad instance which actually satisfies the monad laws will automatically be a functor!

Thankfully, as of GHC 7.10, it's explicitly required that a Monad be an Applicative (and thus a Functor) as part of the definition. See [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.10-latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.2.0/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) for instance.

This is OK since, as I mentioned earlier, it's always been possible to derive the applicative data (`pure` and `<*>`) as well as the functor data (`fmap`) from the data of a monad instance (namely `return` and `>>=`). This all makes sense, since mathematically we know that every monad should be a functor. So if these typeclasses aren't badly named, it should be true for them too!

Now, for completeness, how do we actually derive Applicative and Functor instances from a Monad instance?

For applicatives, `pure` is defined to be `return` and `<*>` is defined to be

```
<*> :: m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
mf <*> mx = do
  f <- mf
  x <- mx
  return $ f x
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to desugar this `do` notation into something using only `return` and `>>=`.

To get from applicatives to functors, you can check that

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
fmap f mx = pure f <*> mx
```

works. As another exercise, can you compose these in order to directly write `fmap` using `return` and `>>=`?

Lastly, as a more mathematical question, you might be interested in *proving* that the Functor laws hold for this definition, provided we assume that the Monad laws hold for the Monad we started with! With the definition of `fmap` in hand, this isn't so hard, and you should definitely try to do it yourself!

---

I hope this helps ^_^